# Auto-Connect to Bluetooth Modem (Android Phone Data Connection)

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, android, wireless-access-point

I can easily get my Win7 to connect to my phone's internet connection via Bluetooth. It's a simple right click -> connect to -> dial up modem.
Thing is, I want to be able to do this automatically whenever my computer wakes up (it's a laptop, so closing the lid makes it sleep and lose its connection), thus not having to connect manually every time I open my lid.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set your bluetooth dialup connection, open internet explorer. In the popup connection window tick the checkbox for auto connect option & connect. Now whenever you try to access internet, connection will be established automatically if your bluetooth device is on. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I look like I use IE? :P

Comment: IE or not (and I think this setting actually applies to all browsers), the Bluetooth connection simply doesn't appear in this tab.